# Revisiting AI-generating content on Vi and Vim

Tags: discussion

In case you missed it, [Stack Exchange is rolling out a banner to let folks know that machine-generated content must be cited to conform with the code of conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/396626/389795). This comes on the heels of [a per-site choice of banner that can include notices about AI bans](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/395881/389795).

### What we need to do as a community

1. Revisit our [original AI discussion, where I think we came to consensus not to allow AI-generated answers](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1591/10604) based on the Stack Overflow ban and subsequent strikes/etc. That is not the goal of this post, which is going to assume that we still enforce a ban on our site (there are some excellent answers on our original discussion in favor of such a ban). If you wish to disagree with that policy, start a new discussion for voting.
2. Decide whether or not we want a "ban banner." This is the goal of this post.

If we want a custom banner, we need to follow [the steps laid out by staff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/395881/389795). Summarizing:

1. Build community consensus that we want a banner.
2. Build community consensus on the custom help text that banner should link to. ([Example from Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy).)
3. If adding a banner, tag [status-review](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-review) for escalation.

In order to keep voting useful, a good answer should fall into one of 3 categories:

- Reasons *not* to have a banner (votes indicate dis/agreement)
- Reasons *to* have a banner (idem.)
- Suggested help text for the banner link (votes indicate dis/approval on the assumption we go forward with a banner)

Comment: I'll be avoiding adding my own answers for now to encourage community input.

Comment: The "original AI policy" link doesn't seem to point to a page saying we have a ban on this site. Is it pointing to the wrong place, or am I missing something?

Comment: I should clarify that @Rich—to me, it points to consensus to disallow AI-generated answers, but maybe it doesn't explicitly state that.

Answer (score 2):

Considering that we have been confronted to AI generated answers to only a very small extend.

Considering that we want to be very inclusive and let people feel that there their contributions are welcome.

I would not add a warning message that could give the perception that genuine answer have the risk to be perceived as not allowed.

At the moment, with the problems we face, I would vote against a banner.

Comment: All fair points. For context, I know of only 2 or 3 posts that have required attention under the ban (but there may be more I’m not aware of).

Comment: I agree with the points above. I'd like to add the minor consideration that people who disregard site policy will not necessarily be deterred by a banner. It's the digital equivalent of a "no trespassing" sign. Sure, somebody *may* pause and think about it. However, we'll all have to live with the visual clutter (until someone comes up with some clever JavaScript to hide the banner).